# Google AdSense reward adds for web

Tags: angular, admob, adsense

I just integrated google firebase add mob inside my mobile application. There is a reward adds that we can monitor and provide rewards for users according to their add views. But how we do it in a web application is there any kind of monitor and reward giving mechanism for google addsenese? There are some alternative add provider that provides reward kind of adds for websites. But it is better to have the same add provider for mobile application and website. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available for Adsense yet,